# .jar works only on my computer, classnotfoundexception on others

Tags: java, path, jvm, classnotfoundexception

I'm building a java project on my Lubuntu computer and while it's working on my computer, when I'm trying to run it on a different one (Windows/Lubuntu) I'm getting

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: geli/BasicApp
>   .....
>   ...
>   ....
>    ............
>   ....
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: geli.BasicApp

Here's the file structure - 
[image]

At the beginning I've thought that it's because of the Linux and Windows path difference but testing it on my other Linux computer gave me the same error that I've got on my windows computer.
I have no clue for the solution and I'd really appreciate any help.

EDIT:
jar file from inside has the libs [image: jar from inside]

Manefiest: 
[image: manefiest]

Comment: You're probably building a JAR that includes only the classes in the current project, not the dependencies, as well. For actually distributing your code, you'll want to build a JAR that includes not only your project's immediate code, but also all the dependencies of your code, as well.

Comment: @MichaelAaronSafyan The jar file containts all of the libraries I'll upload a pic of it

Answer (score 0):

As you are using eclipse you can just follow these steps : 
Right click the project -> Export -> Java -> Runnable jar file

If you want to manually resolve the issue follow the steps:

- Add all the dependant jars in a folder, say "dependencies". Place the folder in the same location of your actual jar
- Now add the the dependency entries in META-INF/MANIFEST.MF file of your jar as below 
  Class-Path: dependencies/dependency1.jar dependencies/dependency2.jar

Comment: Instead of having libs folder inside jar, take them outside and place it alongside FinalProject.jar. FinalProject.jar and libs folder should have the same hierarchy.

Comment: You mean placing the libs together with my own code?